# Property sheet example with use of a PropertyEditor (ControlsFX)

Tags: javafx

I have been searching a lot for any good examples of the use of a ControlsFX PropertySheet but couldn’t find anything but this.

[https://www.google.nl/search?q=Main.java+amazonaws.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=d5aeU5bvBI3k-gan94HQBA#channel=sb&q=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket-assetroot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fcontrolsfx%2Fcontrolsfx+Main.java&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Main.java+amazonaws.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3anl%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=d5aeU5bvBI3k-gan94HQBA#channel=sb&q=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket-assetroot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fcontrolsfx%2Fcontrolsfx+Main.java&rls=org.mozilla%3anl%3aofficial)

In this example, the  ObservableList items which includes NameItem objects, is added to the PropertySheet object in its constructor just like the documentation tells.

http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html

However, as this documentation says, a column of a PropertySheet “provides a PropertyEditor that allows the end user the means to manipulate the property”. It even says that there is a “CheckEditor, ChoiceEditor, TextEditor and FontEditor, among the many editors that are available in the Editors package.”.

I don’t want to be limited to my NameItem example. I also want to add check boxes, choice boxes and other dynamic editor elements. Can anyone please give an example on how to use one or more of the editors to build a simple PropertySheet?

Comment: Have you looked at samples? Specifically HelloPropertySheet sample.

Answer (score 10):

[PropertySheet](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html) does support few property editors out of the box, depending on a property type.

Following example is an extension from ControlsFX sample application. It shows how String, LocalDate, Enum, Boolean and Integer types are mapped to the TextField, DatePicker, ChoiceBox, CheckBox and NumericField respectively.

```
public class PropertySheetExample extends VBox {
    private static Map<String, Object> customDataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    static {
        customDataMap.put("Group 1#My Text", "Same text"); // Creates a TextField in property sheet
        customDataMap.put("Group 1#My Date", LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1)); // Creates a DatePicker
        customDataMap.put("Group 2#My Enum Choice", SomeEnumType.EnumValue); // Creates a ChoiceBox
        customDataMap.put("Group 2#My Boolean", false); // Creates a CheckBox
        customDataMap.put("Group 2#My Number", 500); // Creates a NumericField
    }

    class CustomPropertyItem implements PropertySheet.Item {
        private String key;
        private String category, name;

        public CustomPropertyItem(String key) {
            this.key = key;
            String[] skey = key.split("#");
            category = skey[0];
            name = skey[1];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getType() {
            return customDataMap.get(key).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue() {
            return customDataMap.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            customDataMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public PropertySheetExample {
        ObservableList<PropertySheet.Item> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (String key : customDataMap.keySet())
            list.add(new CustomPropertyItem(key));

        PropertySheet propertySheet = new PropertySheet(list);
        VBox.setVgrow(propertySheet, Priority.ALWAYS);
        getChildren().add(propertySheet);
    }
}
```

This behavior can be further extended in two ways. First, an existing editor can be used for types which are not supported by default property editor factory. Following example sets new property editor factory which will create ChoiceBox for List<String> type. For other types it delegates editor creation to the default factory.

```
SimpleObjectProperty<Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>> propertyEditorFactory = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "propertyEditor", new DefaultPropertyEditorFactory());

propertySheet.setPropertyEditorFactory(new Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>() {
    @Override
    public PropertyEditor<?> call(PropertySheet.Item param) {
        if(param.getValue() instanceof List) {
            return Editors.createChoiceEditor(param, (List) param.getValue());
        }

        return propertyEditorFactory.get().call(param);
    }
});
```

And finally, we can create custom editor and override `getPropertyEditorClass()` method from the [PropertySheet.Item](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.Item.html) to return the custom editor type. In that case, default property editor factory will create the editor, and there is no need to override the factory method.

Comment: Your answer is great but I cant find where to put this list to property thingy. When my data is selected, it becomes text again for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if this happens to you because of the property sheet - if you see the ComboBox when window is created it should stay ComboBox all the time. I generally extend the PropertySheet class and call setPropertyEditorFactory() method in the constructor. Then I put that my class into the window and that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Even after looking at the samples and trying to find out more, I was also very confused as to how to change the types of user input in a property sheet. It took me about a while to work out but it turns out the answer is relatively simple.

The key is the PropertyEditorFactory which can be set directly onto the PropertySheet using `setPropertyEditorFactory(Callback<PropertySheet.Item,PropertyEditor<?>> factory)` In this callback the method returns a type of PropertyEditor which are contained within the Editors package. As the call provides the PropertySheet.Item parameter, you can retrieve the value being set, in my example below I checked the type of the returned object to provide a relevant editor.

```
propertySheet.setPropertyEditorFactory(new Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>() {
    @Override
    public PropertyEditor<?> call(Item param) {
        if(param.getValue() instanceof String[]) {   
            return Editors.createChoiceEditor(param, choices);
         } else if (param.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
            return Editors.createCheckEditor(param);
         } else if (param.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
            return Editors.createNumericEditor(param);
         } else {
            return Editors.createTextEditor(param);
         }
     }
});
```

Once you override this editor factory however, you must provide a PropertyEditor for every type of setting you need, for instance if you only returned `Editors.createNumericEditor(param);` but had String options, you'll get an exception. Also don't override getPropertyEditorClass() from PropertySheet.Item which is where I wasted most of my time. Hope this helps anyone else trying to do this!

Comment: where should I type this becuase whenever I choose something from the choice editor, it becomes a textfield and string again

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any example for a custom `Editor` for the `PropertySheet`, but I think I figured it out now. In my case I simply want to use a `Slider` as an editor for a `Number`. This may not be practical, since you would have no way of seeing the value of the Slider, but I imagine the Slider could simply be replaced by a pane with the slider and a label.

To start with, we need our implementation of `Item`, here a slightly modified version of the controlsfx-samples. The `Map` was moved into this class, but could be anywhere. You might not want to use a map at all though, since it is already somewhat impractical to have the category and the name combined; plus there is no room to create descriptions for the items.

```
public class CustomPropertyItem implements PropertySheet.Item {
    public static Map<String, Object> customDataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    static {
        customDataMap.put("basic.My Text", "Same text"); // Creates a TextField in property sheet
        customDataMap.put("basic.My Date", LocalDate.of(2016, Month.JANUARY, 1)); // Creates a DatePicker
        customDataMap.put("misc.My Enum", SomeEnum.ALPHA); // Creates a ChoiceBox
        customDataMap.put("misc.My Boolean", false); // Creates a CheckBox
        customDataMap.put("misc.My Number", 500); // Creates a NumericField
        customDataMap.put("misc.My Color", Color.ALICEBLUE); // Creates a ColorPicker
    }

    private String key;
    private String category, name;

    public CustomPropertyItem(String key) 
    {
        this.key = key;
        String[] skey = key.split("\\.", 2);
        category = skey[0];
        name = skey[1];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType() {
        return customDataMap.get(key).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        // doesn't really fit into the map
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return customDataMap.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        customDataMap.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<ObservableValue<? extends Object>> getObservableValue() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Class<? extends PropertyEditor<?>>> getPropertyEditorClass() {
        // for an item of type number, specify the type of editor to use
        if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(getType())) return Optional.of(NumberSliderEditor.class);

        // ... return other editors for other types

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Next up, the `PropertyEditor` implementation, which is a `Node` and a set of methods that connect the property item value with a control. The first constructor is necessary for the implementation **and** the second constructor is needed, because the method `Editors.createCustomEditor(Item)` uses reflection to look for this constructor. You do not have to use this method, but the default PropertyEditorFactory most likely relies on this.
If you want to avoid reflection for some reason, you don't need to override `getPropertyEditorClass()` in *your* `Item` and you can use `setPropertyEditorFactory(Callback)` and create a new instance of your `PropertyEditor` in there.
Note that you don't need to use `setPropertyEditorFactory(Callback)` at all (in this example).

```
public class NumberSliderEditor extends AbstractPropertyEditor<Number, Slider> {

    public NumberSliderEditor(Item property, Slider control) 
    {
        super(property, control);
    }

    public NumberSliderEditor(Item item)
    {
        this(item, new Slider());
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Number n) {
        this.getEditor().setValue(n.doubleValue());
    }

    @Override
    protected ObservableValue<Number> getObservableValue() {
        return this.getEditor().valueProperty();
    }

}
```

From here on you just create your `PropertySheet` and add all the map entries.

```
PropertySheet propertySheet = new PropertySheet();
for (String key : CustomPropertyItem.customDataMap.keySet()) propertySheet.getItems().add(new CustomPropertyItem(key));
```

I hope this is helpful to anyone, as there don't seem to be any examples out there that show the use of a custom `Editor`. The only hint towards this is the javadoc of `Item.getPropertyEditorClass()`, which has a default interface implementation so you normally wouldn't look at it. The fact that there is an answer here saying not to look at this method didn't help either :/

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been working on Javafx with `PropertySheet`, below is the simple and quick practice:
first we need model class to reflect the gui:

```
public class Person {
    int age;
    boolean isLive = true;
    String name = "Yimkong";
    // ... getter and setter method
}
```

Then is the Main class:

```
public class PropertiesSheetTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Person bean = new Person();
        ObservableList<PropertySheet.Item> properties = BeanPropertyUtils.getProperties(bean);
        PropertySheet propertySheet = new PropertySheet(properties);
        propertySheet.setSearchBoxVisible(false);
        propertySheet.setModeSwitcherVisible(false);
        DefaultPropertyEditorFactory defaultPropertyEditorFactory = new DefaultPropertyEditorFactory();
        propertySheet.setPropertyEditorFactory(new Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>() {
            @Override
            public PropertyEditor<?> call(PropertySheet.Item param) {
                if(param.getName().equals("age")){
                    List<Integer> ageList = new ArrayList<>();
                    ageList.add(3);
                    ageList.add(5);
                    ageList.add(10);
                    return Editors.createChoiceEditor(param,ageList);
                }
                return defaultPropertyEditorFactory.call(param);
            }
        });
        VBox vBox = new VBox(propertySheet);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: result gui]

**Advantages:**

- easy to develop via BeanPropertyUtils, reflect to java bean
- we can remove some of the setter methods in model class if we don't want user to change any content on GUI
- if we are not satisfy with the default PropertyEditor, we can overwrite by our own's.

This basically satisfy most scenarios.By the way, it can also support Enum field in model class with ChoiceEditor as Default.

Comment: Nice answer.  Additionally, if you want the property changes in the model to be observable then use JavaFX properties to represent them rather than raw types.